# System.Globalization CultureInfo CultureNotFoundException

Tags: c#, exception, registry, globalization, cultureinfo

I followed the numerous guides of how to add a custom culture and on ocal machine if worked perfectly. 
However, I got CultureNotFoundException on the CultureInfo constructor on a development server with error on the name. the nlp file was created correctly and i suspect the registry step was the issue, but i couldn't find any resource about it. more over, it corrupted any other language mapping on the machine for all other applications.
Eventually I followed the [The Developer's Guide to Building Global Windows and Web Applications: Chapter 11 - Custom Cultures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15175/NET-Internationalization-The-Developer-s-Guide-to) on codeproject and replaced an existing culture with the needed modifications, which works correctly.
Still I wonder why my original custom culture didn't work and the replacement did.
in any case i also wanted to share my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The Locale Builder tool would be the preferred way to build locales for Windows 10 machines - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41158 - however locales built with the current Locale Builder tool may not work in all scenarios on older OS's.  What OS were you running?

CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder will still work, however it has not been updated with some of the fields/concepts in newer versions of Windows, so it may not have the expected behavior in some cases.

Given that you said that other things were corrupted it does seem like you're hitting the mismatch between the version that the locale/culture was built for and the version it is being installed on.